# EAR lib folder vs MANIFEST.MF Class-Path entry

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, ear, manifest.mf

Does it have the same effect of placing *libary.jar* inside the `/lib` folder of an *EAR* or placing it on the *EAR* root and listing it on the *EAR*'s `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` Class-Path? I.e. does both approaches make the library available to all Java EE modules inside the EAR? Which overrides which? Is there some reason to favor other over another?

Comment: Listing classes in a `Class-Path` entry of the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of an EAR file is unlikely* to do anything at all. `Class-Path` entries only work in JAR files and WAR files. Furthermore, in a Java EE deployment these entries can only refer to other JAR files that have been placed somewhere in the EAR. *a vendor extension might do something with it, but not any that I'm aware of.

Comment: That is weird. Our project is deployed on standard weblogic installation, and all the library jars indeed resides on the EAR root, and are listed on the manifest.